# camunda doesn't set the variable as expected

Tags: java, camunda

I have this bpmn model :

[image]

all tasks have forms with just one name field, the name field value of task1 should determine where to go from the exclusive gateway.

It's stored in file called test1.bpmn, in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" id="Definitions_1" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="1.11.3">
  <bpmn:process id="process1" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0ce6se1</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:startEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_0ce6se1" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="task1" />
    <bpmn:exclusiveGateway id="gateway1">
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_0gm7v19</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1oyhcn0</bpmn:outgoing>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0b9aff3</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:exclusiveGateway>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1oyhcn0" sourceRef="gateway1" targetRef="task3">
      <bpmn:conditionExpression xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${name=="amer"}]]></bpmn:conditionExpression>
    </bpmn:sequenceFlow>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_0b9aff3" sourceRef="gateway1" targetRef="task2">
      <bpmn:conditionExpression xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${name=="amer"}]]></bpmn:conditionExpression>
    </bpmn:sequenceFlow>
    <bpmn:endEvent id="EndEvent_11431dt">
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_0xtdrz5</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_12digm0</bpmn:incoming>
    </bpmn:endEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_0xtdrz5" sourceRef="task3" targetRef="EndEvent_11431dt" />
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_12digm0" sourceRef="task2" targetRef="EndEvent_11431dt" />
    <bpmn:userTask id="task2" name="task2" camunda:formKey="task2form">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:formData>
          <camunda:formField id="name" type="string" />
        </camunda:formData>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_0b9aff3</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_12digm0</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:userTask>
    <bpmn:userTask id="task3" name="task3" camunda:formKey="task3form">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:formData>
          <camunda:formField id="name" type="string" />
        </camunda:formData>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_1oyhcn0</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0xtdrz5</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:userTask>
    <bpmn:userTask id="task1" name="task1" camunda:formKey="task1form">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:formData>
          <camunda:formField id="name" label="name" type="string" />
        </camunda:formData>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_0ce6se1</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0gm7v19</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:userTask>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_0gm7v19" sourceRef="task1" targetRef="gateway1" />
  </bpmn:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="process1">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_2" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="153" y="102" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="126" y="138" width="90" height="20" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_0ce6se1_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_0ce6se1">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="189" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="235" y="120" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="167" y="99" width="90" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="ExclusiveGateway_1t2paul_di" bpmnElement="gateway1" isMarkerVisible="true">
        <dc:Bounds x="385" y="95" width="50" height="50" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="410" y="149" width="0" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_1oyhcn0_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_1oyhcn0">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="410" y="145" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="410" y="306" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="394" y="306" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="425" y="219.5" width="0" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_0b9aff3_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_0b9aff3">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="435" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="465" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="465" y="134" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="495" y="134" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="480" y="121" width="0" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="EndEvent_11431dt_di" bpmnElement="EndEvent_11431dt">
        <dc:Bounds x="471" y="346" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="489" y="386" width="0" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_0xtdrz5_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_0xtdrz5">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="394" y="306" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="433" y="306" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="433" y="364" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="471" y="364" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="448" y="329" width="0" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_12digm0_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_12digm0">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="545" y="174" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="545" y="260" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="489" y="260" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="489" y="346" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="517" y="239" width="0" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="UserTask_15n4esu_di" bpmnElement="task2">
        <dc:Bounds x="495" y="94" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="UserTask_0q3p8hg_di" bpmnElement="task3">
        <dc:Bounds x="294" y="266" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="UserTask_17boswh_di" bpmnElement="task1">
        <dc:Bounds x="235" y="80" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_0gm7v19_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_0gm7v19">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="335" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="385" y="120" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="315" y="99" width="90" height="12" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

and I have this jersey resource :

```
@Path("process")
public class Process {

    private static ProcessEngine engine = ProcessEngineManager.getEngine();
    private static ProcessInstance instance;
    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     */
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("start")
    public void start(){
        instance = engine.getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey("process1");
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("next")
    public String next(@FormParam("name") String name){
        engine.getRuntimeService().setVariable(instance.getId(),"name",name);
        Map<String,Object> formParams = new HashMap<>();
        formParams.put("name",name);
        Task testTask = engine.getTaskService().createTaskQuery()
                .list().get(0);
        engine.getFormService().submitTaskForm(testTask.getId(),formParams);
        return testTask.getName();
    }
}
```

and ProcessEngineManager:

```
public class ProcessEngineManager {
    private static ProcessEngine engine;
    public static ProcessEngine getEngine(){
        if(engine==null) {
            engine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
            engine.getRepositoryService().createDeployment()
                    .addClasspathResource("workflowtest/test1.bpmn")
                    .deploy();
        }
        return engine;
    }
}
```

and camunda.cfg.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">

        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000" />
        <property name="jdbcDriver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUsername" value="sa" />
        <property name="jdbcPassword" value="" />

        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The problem is that when I make a request to start and then a request to next with name as "amer", this line :

```
engine.getRuntimeService().setVariable(instance.getId(),"name",name);
```

Doesn't set the variable as verified by `instance.getVariables` and that causes an exception at the line of `submitTaskForm` like this:

> org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-02004 No
>   outgoing sequence flow for the element with id 'gateway1' could be
>   selected for continuing the process.

I tried `setVariableLocal` instead , same result.

Why doesn't it set the variable ? and what Can I do to solve the problem.

Comment: Check the sequence flow conditions. Both are `name=="amer"` and I guess the value you submitted is something other than `"amer"`.

Comment: @thorben I submitted amer, the same result

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I'm calling the REST API in a wrong way which caused `name` to be null, it now works great.